# Responsive Adsense refresh after a screen orientation change

Tags: responsive-design, adsense

I've completed my responsive design, except the adsense implementation.
When for example a visitor changes the orientation of the tablet, the size of the ad should change automatically.
At the moment, I'm not getting it to work without a page refresh.
The ad only changes when I refresh the page, but that's not what a visitor would do.

According to [Adsense support](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en) it has already been implemented:

> Support for ad size changes after a screen orientation change. If your responsive page changes its layout following a device orientation change (e.g., when a tablet or phone goes from portrait to landscape), we’ll request and load a new ad of the correct dimensions to fit the new page layout.

However, I'm not getting it to work. Am I understanding it the wrong way, or am I missing something?

If it's not supported by Adsense yet, is there a workaround (allowed by adsense)?

EDIT: I just found out it is actually working on my smartphone. It just doesn't work with window resizing, but that's not really a problem. So I guess this is solved.

Comment: Please post the code you have used to generate this problem.  Try a jsfiddle to better show the problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Just the standard Adsense responsive code. It doesn't work with browser resizing, but does with device flip.

Answer (score 2):

Pay close attention to the official "Technical considerations" at [About responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689)

- Your site uses third-party JavaScript
- The parent container has no width set

In my case, responsive design was not setting an explicit width on viewports below 467x.  As a result, the units would resize when going from portrait to landscape, but not vice versa from landscape to portrait.  This resulted in a an ad unit stretching the content column wider than the viewport, and worse no ability to zoom out.

Setting an explicit width for the ad unit using a media query solved the issue, and now the units resize and cache exactly as described.